# Is the training tag for lessons or for practicing/exercising?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked a question about sailing lessons. There were no tags that were unequivocally related to learning something: learning, lessons, instruction, and so on don't seem to exist. There is a [training](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) tag, and some of the questions were about being taught, but most were about exercising or practicing (eg training in the offseason, using a hangboard, etc.) There is no tag wiki for the tag, so I guess there's no current opinion.

Should there be a lessons, school, instruction, learning kind of tag? Should someone create a tag wiki for training to make it clear what it is and isn't for? I have the rep to create tags, but wanted to get an opinion from the community first.

Comment: I think it'd be perfectly valid for you to create the wiki for this? Why wait for someone else to do it?