# Do we have a tag for "fitness training"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I was reading [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19606/how-many-days-does-it-reach-hiking-x-miles-per-day) and realized it didn't have a tag relevant to physical fitness.

I wanted to add the [training](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) tag, but the description doesn't seem fit for a "fitness training". It says:

> Questions referencing the learning or expanding of a skill under the tutelage of a peer, through a course, or through various learning materials eg, books, the internet etc.

Do we have a tag for "fitness training" or equivalent?

If not, should we create it?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I've wondered about it myself. There's a [related meta question](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/is-the-training-tag-for-lessons-or-for-practicing-exercising?rq=1) @Kate Gregory asked in 2013 with no answers from the community. At that time, no wiki had been written yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't make a separate tag for fitness because any regimen to help you do X better in the TGO context will have an element of fitness to it.

I suggest rewriting the tag description.  Putting *tutelage of a peer* first makes it sound haphazard and amateurish.  And, almost by definition, if you are training under the instruction of someone, that someone is not your peer during the training session.  You may be her peer 23 hours of the day, but not during the hour of training.

So here is a minor rewrite to get things started:

> Questions about learning or improving a skill or becoming more fit in an
>   organized manner through working with an instructor, or with an
>   expert friend, or taking a group course, or following a course in,
>   e.g., a book, a video or online.